# headScript()->appendFile has the same behaviour as headScript()->prependFile from view

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I ran into some problem. appendFile does not seem to work from the view. It has the same behaviour if I change it to prependFile.

layout.phtml

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <?php
        $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'); 
        $this->headScript()->appendFile('/theme/javascripts/application.js'); 
        $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/own.js'); 
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
        <?php echo $this->headScript() ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

index.phtml

```
<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/another.js') ?>
```

output

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>

</head>
<body>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/another.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/javascripts/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/own.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see /js/another.js will be the first js. That's not what I want, I want to put it as last. Anyone knows what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`/js/another.js` is at the beginning because `layout.phtml` is called first and then when you call `<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>`  it calls for the `index.phtml` file.

Now in your code you've:
    `<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>`
        `<?php echo $this->headScript() ?>`

So it's actually calling the `layout()` and hence the `index.phtml` and then its calling the `headscript()` which has the rest of them. Its appending the `js` mentioned in the `index.phtml` and then appends the rest from `headscript()`. Try the other way around...

You should try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <?php
            $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'); 
            $this->headScript()->appendFile('/theme/javascripts/application.js'); 
            $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/own.js'); 
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->headScript() ?> 
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ideally you should output all your scripts in the `<HEAD>` section.

Comment: I would like to put it before the body tag for speed optimization.

Comment: if you want to load all the js in the end, then keep your code unchanged and change `<?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/another.js') ?>` to `<?php $this->headScript()->prependFile('/js/another.js') ?>` in `index.phtml`

Comment: Actually this is backwards, see my answer. The view script is rendered before the layout. Otherwise you wouldn't be able add JS to the `<head>` from a view script at all.

Answer (score 0):

The view script is rendered *before* the layout, so when you append `/js/another.js`, there are no other scripts, and this is why the ones later added by your layout end up after it.

You should be able to achieve the order you want by changing all of the `appendFile()` calls in the layout to `prependFile()`. (And you might need to reverse their order since you're now prepending.) The execution order should then be:

- View script appends `/js/another.js`
- Layout prepends `/js/own.js`
- Layout prepends `/theme/javascripts/application.js`
- Layout prepends `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js`

Also, you might want to consider using the inline script helper (which works in the same way) for this, as having head script outputting scripts in the `<body>` might confuse future developers working on your code.